# Using TransactedInstaller - do I still need to use Rollback?

Tags: .net, windows-installer, topshelf

I've been using Topshelf for 3 years now, but only in simple use cases. I've started a new job and suggested using Topshelf but they override the Rollback method of the Installer class. For example they use it to call "http delete urlacl ...".

Topshelf doesn't expose BeforeRollback or AfterRollback. I'm not against submitting a pull request, but I want to know beforehand if I even need rollback functionality or not? Also possibly is there already a way of handling this using Topshelf?

Comment: All this BeforeThis AfterThat stuff is fine if you want to use a script to call the EXE and install it.  But if you are using windows installer (MSI)  it's a complete antipattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was surfacing the BeforeRollback and AfterRollback events to Topshelf's public interface along side the other installer events that are exposed. I've submitted a pull request to the developers, but until they accept it you may find the source with my updates here: https://github.com/developmentalmadness/Topshelf

Answer (score 1):

With all respect to TopShelf, they might have a good pattern for creating services ( I don't know, I've never used them )  but if they are still using custom actions in their deployment then they still have missed the boat with how Windows Installer is designed to work. I don't fault them because there is much out there written on the subject that is suboptimal from an MSI perspective.

I first wrote about this 6 years ago:

[MSI vs .NET](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2006/07/msi-vs-net.html)

The problem started with Visual Studio Deployment Projects which didn't expose the underlying native capabilities of MSI.  Instead the created Installer Class custom actions which encourages reinventing the wheel with more fragile solution. MSI isn't about injecting out of process imperative code, it's about declarative programming.

A cleaner way to handling a service can be found here at:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

The concept is to encapsulate the service as a merge module and add to InstallShield.  It could also be added to a Visual Studio Deployment Project or it could be refactored to be pure WiX.

Same goes for netsh commands.  You shouldn't have to have all this custom code and try to get all the servicing strategies correct.  Instead use the built in [FirewallException Element (Firewall Extension)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/firewall_xsd_firewallexception.htm) of WiX ( again can be encapsulated and used with other tools ) and let it do the hard work for you.

If this seems interesting but unachievable, just hit me up and I'll show you.  Until someone bothers to rewrite the books, I just have to convince one developer at a time.

Comment: We are using Wix for all our deployment needs. Including 3 production Windows services. Its pretty straightforward all the way. Looking up Topshelf, I cannot discourage OP enough to not use it: A tool like this can never fulfill all deployment needs, nor does it teach you properly the basics of windows services, which aint that hard.

Comment: Here's a video on how to create a simple MSI using WiX to deploy a service.  It's using the built-in VS Windows Service project but it would work just fine with TopShelf also. http://blog.iswix.com/2013/01/iswix-20130134-released.html

Comment: While I appreciate your feedback, and I get your dislike for .NET installer code, Topshelf is a mature, well-tested library used by projects like NServiceBus. It frees me from having to write a ServiceBase class and allows me to write a service w/o having to install it as a service during development. Then the whole thing can be deployed with a few command line switches (usually, just one).

Comment: Also it's open source, I can inspect to see what it's doing if the documentation doesn't tell me - a closed-source, poorly documented solution has no appeal for me. As for netsh - I'm not configuring the firewall, I'm configuring http.sys for WCF. @CasperLeonNielsen - I understand Windows Services plenty.

Comment: Alas you don't understand Windows Installer though.

Comment: We'll just say I haven't seen any arguments that have convinced me that I need it.